# Magento - grid filter using ajax reloads the whole page

Tags: php, magento

I'm using a grid in magento admin (extending `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` ) to display the content of a database table. I saw in some other modules that there's an option to be set in the constructor to use ajax reloads instead of page reloads 

this is my constructor:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('myGrid');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setVarNameFilter('my_filter');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
}
```

but when I click the filter of the grid and click the search button, it reloads the WHOLE page (including header, footer,...) INSIDE the grid div.
Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: not sure, but probably some javascript is also applied to grid ... take a look at .phtml file for some other grids.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the solution:
First I had to add the following function to the grid class

```
 public function getGridUrl()
 {
   return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
 }
```

each ajax call will then be sent to this url (and the corresponding controller action) rather then the pages url.
then I added the following bit to the layout XML file:

```
<module_controller_grid>
  <reference name="root">
    <block type="package/gridblockname" name="root" output="toHtml" />
  </reference>
</module_controller_grid>
```

this overwrites the root element and displays only the grid block. hence my ajax call will only load the updated grid itself and won't include header, footer, etc.

Comment: I have the problem that the ajax loading window does not close after successful turn to next page. In my controller action I tried return; return 1; return true; echo 1; etc. nothing worked. How can I close the ajax window?

Comment: Also had the same problem with the spinner not disappearing. Figured it was caused by my `Vendor_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Model_Grid.php` not having set `$this->setId("some_id");` inside `__construct()` function

Answer (score 13):

You could also add a "gridAction" method to your admin controller instead of creating a layout xml

```
public function gridAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
           $this->getLayout()->createBlock('{Namespace}/adminhtml_{Module}/grid')->toHtml()
    ); 
}
```

Assuming:

Block Path : 
/app/code/local/{Namespace}/{Module}/Block/Adminhtml/{Module}/Grid.php

Answer (score 13):

Add follwing code into __construct() function in :

`app/code/local/[Name_Space]/[Module_Name]/Block/Adminhtml/[Module_Name]/Grid.php file.`

```
$this->setUseAjax(true);
```

Now Add following function at last of this file.

```
public function getGridUrl()
  {
      return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
  }
```

Now Add following function at last in :

`app/code/local/[Name_Space]/[Module_Name]/controllers/Adminhtml/[Module_Name]Controller.php file.`

```
public function gridAction()
     {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
               $this->getLayout()->createBlock('[Module_Name]/adminhtml_[Module_Name]_grid')->toHtml()
        );
     }
```

*Courtesy : Nirav Kadiya*

Answer (score 4):

The Nirav Kadiya almost works for me but I create the gridAction function like this in the Admin Controller:

```
public function gridAction()
     {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
               $this->getLayout()->createBlock('[Module_Name]_Block_Adminhtml_[Model_Name]_Grid')->toHtml()
        );
     }
```

And include this in de Grid file

```
public function getGridUrl()
    {
          return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }
```